# Which layer of a deep learning model (DenseNet-121) to use as output when using model as feature extractor

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, feature-extraction, image-classification

im having trouble deciding or being sure what layer of a densenet-121 (fined-tuned model) to use for feature extraction.

I have the following model (is based on DenseNet-121 but I added a classification layer because I have trained it to classify the image into 7 classes). These are the last layers of my model:
[image]

However, Im having trouble figuring out which layer to use (BatchNormalization or the relu). I want to have a vector of len(4096). Is there a difference of output from the two layers? Which one is the recommended one to use?

Answer (score 0):

if you are doing classification you want the dense_3 layer as the model output. The batch normalization layer and the relu layer each produce an output of shape(2,2,1024). 4096 is the number of trainable parameters for the layer

Comment: Not doing classification. I'm doing feature extraction. The model has been used for classification. But I want to get a feature representation (vector) of the image.